# How to set space in stackview, like Spacer in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, uikit, uistackview

How can I give spacing like Spacer in SwiftUI in stackview, not exact spacing?

```
private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.distribution = .equalCentering
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    //stackView.spacing = 100
    return stackView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUI()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
}

func setUI() {
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(usersTextLabel)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(seeMoreButton)
    //stackView.addArrangedSubview(emptyView)
    
    stackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(45)
        make.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(15)
        make.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(15)
    }
}
```

I tried to add empty view and give it some width. Is there another way to do it?

[image]

Comment: I think a simple solution would be to use distribution fill and lower the horizontal content hugging priority of the `usersTextButton`. That label would then expand to fill the extra space but, as the text is leading aligned, would look correct.

Comment: A possibly better solution would be to use distribution fill and add an empty `UIView` between the label and the button. I think the view’s horizontal content hugging priority will default to lower than the label and button (and reduce it, if not) so that the empty view will expand to fill the space.

Comment: Note also that your example code is creating two leading constraints for the stack view. I expect one should be trailing.

Comment: (I meant to say `usersTextLabel` in my first comment but cannot edit it.)

Comment: Hi, thank you for help. Adding empty UIView was the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI's layout system is very different from the constraint system of AutoLayout, so oftentimes there is no "direct translations".

A `Spacer`, according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/spacer), is

> an adaptive view with no content that expands as much as it can. For example, when placed within an `HStack`, a spacer expands horizontally as much as the stack allows, moving sibling views out of the way, within the limits of the stack’s size.

So we need to create a `UIView` that acts like that. Since it should expand as much as it can, the distribution of the stack view should be `.fill` (which is the default), not `.equalCentering`:

```
stackView.distribution = .fill
```

Note that "as much as it can" implies that the stack view should have a defined/maximum width. Otherwise it could expand indefinitely. Your stack view currently lacks this. You only constrained its top and left edges.

From what I observed, in SwiftUI, `HStack`s can expand up to the bounds of its parent, so in this case you should constraint the `trailing` edge of your `UIStackView` too, defining its width.

```
// similar to .padding(15)
make.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(-15)
```

Then, assuming the other arranged views have an intrinsic/fixed width, you can just add a plain old `UIView` as an arranged subview of the stack view:

```
let v = UIView()
stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
```

The view will automatically expand to fill the space.

If you want multiple spacers, you will need to specify their relative widths. The SwiftUI behaviour seems to be that all spacers in the same stack have the same width. So if you want 2 spacers, you can add a equal width constraint:

```
spacer1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spacer2.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

If you have more spacers, just add more constraints.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for detailed answer! Now I have better understanding of how it works.